# The Ho-Lee Model (1986)'s Bond Call Option Pricing

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

### (My Question)

I solved the following questions. However, if you know the other solutions, please let me know those along with computation processes. Besides, $W_t$ is a S.B.M.

---

### (the details in this model)

See the details in this model at the following cross link site.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3332466/the-ho-lee-model-1986

---

### (Cross-link)

I have posted the same question on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3339590/the-ho-lee-model-1986s-bond-option-pricing-solved-by-myself

---

### Lemma for (7)

Let $X$ be a centered Gaussian random variable with variance $v^2$. Namely, $X \sim N(v^2, v^2)$. One has
\begin{eqnarray}
E^{ \{ \mathbb{Q}, \ X \}} \left[ \left( e^{m+X} - K \right)^+ \right] = e^{m+ v^2/2} N\left(  v + \frac{m - \log K}{v} \right) - K N\left( \frac{m - \log K}{v} \right) 
\end{eqnarray}

---

### (Original Questions)

(1) Derive the S.D.E satisfied by $t \rightarrow P(t, T)$.

(2) Derive the S.D.E satisfied by $t \rightarrow exp( - \int^t_0 r_s ds ) \cdot P(t, T)$.

(3) Express the conditional expectation
\begin{eqnarray}
E^{\mathbb{P}} \left[ \frac{ d \tilde{ \mathbb{P} } }{d \mathbb{P} } \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right]
\end{eqnarray}
in terms of $P(t, T)$, $P(0, T)$ and $exp( -\int^t_0 r_s ds )$, $t \in [0, T]$.

(4) Find a S.D.E satisfied by 
\begin{eqnarray}
t \rightarrow E^{\mathbb{P}} \left[ \frac{ d \tilde{ \mathbb{P} } }{d \mathbb{P} } \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right]
\end{eqnarray}
(5) Compute the density $d \tilde{ \mathbb{P} } /d \mathbb{P} $ of the forward measure with respect to $\mathbb{P}$ by solving the S.D.E of (4).

(6) Using the Girsanov Theorem 2.1, compute the dynamics of $r_t$ under the forward measure.

(7) Compute the price
\begin{eqnarray}
E^{\mathbb{P}} \left[ -\exp \left( \int^t_0 r_s ds \right) \cdot ( P(T,S) - K )^+  \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right]  = P(t, T)  E^{ \tilde{ \mathbb{P} } } \left[  ( P(T,S) - K )^+  \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right] 
\end{eqnarray}
of a bond call option at time $t \geq 0$.

---

(1) My answer

- Recall what one considered in Exercise 5.1.(1) and the definition of $dr_t=\theta dt+ \sigma dW_t$ at in Exercise 4.1. Moreover, recall the result of Exercise 5.1.(2) that is $r_t = r_0 + \theta t+ \sigma W_t$.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  P(t, T) &=&\exp \left( - r_t (T-t) - \frac{1}{2} \theta (T-t)^2  + \frac{ \sigma^2}{6}  (T-t)^3  \right) \\
  &=&\exp \left( - ( r_0 + \theta t+ \sigma W_t) (T-t) - \frac{1}{2} \theta (T-t)^2  + \frac{ \sigma^2}{6}  (T-t)^3  \right)
  \end{eqnarray}
- Use It$\hat{o}$'s formula.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  d P(t, T) &=& \left( - \theta (T-t) + ( r_0 + \theta t+ \sigma W_t) \right) P(t, T) dt \nonumber \\
  && \qquad + \left(  \frac{1}{2} \ 2 \ \theta (T-t) - \frac{ \sigma^2}{6} \ 3 \  (T-t)^2  \right) P(t, T) dt \nonumber \\
  && \qquad - \sigma (T-t) P(t, T) dW_t +  \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 (T-t)^2 P(t, T) d [W_t] \\
  \frac{ d P(t, T) }{  P(t, T) } &=& \left( - \theta (T-t) +  r_t \right)  dt %\nonumber \\
  %&& \qquad 
  + \left(  \ \theta (T-t) - \frac{ \sigma^2}{2}  (T-t)^2  \right) dt \nonumber \\
  && \qquad \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad - \sigma (T-t) dW_t +  \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 (T-t)^2 dt \\
  &=& r_t dt - \sigma (T-t) dW_t  
  \end{eqnarray}

$\square$

(2) My answer

- Apply It$\hat{o}$'s formula according to the instructions of the question. When applying It$\hat{o}$'s formula, let $f(t, p)=exp( -\int^t_0 r_s ds ) \ p$.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  && d \left( \exp \left( -\int^t_0 r_s ds \right)  \ P(t, T)  \right) \\
  && \quad = -r_t   \exp \left( -\int^t_0 r_s ds \right)  \ P(t, T)  dt  + \exp\left(  -\int^t_0 r_s ds \right) dP(t, T)  \nonumber \\
  &&  \qquad + \frac{1}{2} \ 0 \ d \left[  P(t, T) \right]  \\
  && \quad = -r_t   \exp \left( -\int^t_0 r_s ds \right)  \ P(t, T)  dt  \nonumber \\
  &&  \qquad + r_t   \exp \left( -\int^t_0 r_s ds \right)  \ P(t, T)  dt   \nonumber \\
  &&  \qquad - \sigma (T-t) \exp \left( -\int^t_0 r_s ds \right)  \ P(t, T)  dW_t \\
  && \quad = - \sigma (T-t) \exp \left( -\int^t_0 r_s ds \right)  \ P(t, T)  dW_t 
  \end{eqnarray}

$\square$

(3) My answer

- Recall (1). $P(t , T)$ has only one time parameter $t$. In other words, $P(t , T)$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$ measurable. Moreover, $P(0 , T)$ is also $\mathcal{F}_t$ measurable. 
  \begin{eqnarray}
  P(t, T) &=&\exp \left( - ( r_0 + \theta t+ \sigma W_t) (T-t) - \frac{1}{2} \theta (T-t)^2  + \frac{ \sigma^2}{6}  (T-t)^3  \right)
  \end{eqnarray}
- Recall the definition of $d \tilde{ \mathbb{P} } / d \mathbb{P} $.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  \frac{ d \tilde{ \mathbb{P} } }{d \mathbb{P} } & \equiv& \frac{1}{P(0, T)} \exp \left( -\int^T_0 r_s ds \right) 
  \end{eqnarray}
- One calculates this question with the above conditions in mind.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  E^{\mathbb{P}} \left[ \frac{ d \tilde{ \mathbb{P} } }{d \mathbb{P} } \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right] &=& E^{\mathbb{P}} \left[  \frac{1}{P(0, T)} \exp \left( -\int^T_0 r_s ds \right)  \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right]  \\
  &=&  \frac{1}{P(0, T)} E^{\mathbb{P}} \left[  \exp \left( -\int^t_0 r_s ds -\int^T_t r_s ds \right)  \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right]  \\
  &=&  \frac{1}{P(0, T)} \exp \left( -\int^t_0 r_s ds \right) E^{\mathbb{P}} \left[  \exp \left( -\int^T_t r_s ds \right)  \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right]  
  \end{eqnarray}
- Here, one computes the expectation value with the policy of eliminating the integral.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  E^{\mathbb{P}} \left[  \exp \left( -\int^T_t r_s ds \right)  \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right]  &=&  E^{\mathbb{P}} \left[  \frac{P(t, T)}{P(t, T)} \exp \left( -\int^T_t r_s ds \right)  \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right] \\
  &=& P(t, T) E^{\mathbb{P}} \left[  \frac{1}{P(t, T) \exp \left( \int^T_t r_s ds \right)}   \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right] \\
  &=& P(t, T) E^{\mathbb{P}} \left[  \frac{1}{P(T, T) }   \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right] \\
  &=& P(t, T) E^{\mathbb{P}} \left[ \  \frac{1}{1} \  \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right] \\
  &=& P(t, T) 
  \end{eqnarray}
- Substitute the above result into the expectation value.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  E^{\mathbb{P}} \left[ \frac{ d \tilde{ \mathbb{P} } }{d \mathbb{P} } \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right] &=&  \frac{1}{P(0, T)} \exp \left( -\int^t_0 r_s ds \right) E^{\mathbb{P}} \left[  \exp \left( -\int^T_t r_s ds \right)  \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right]  \\
  &=&  \frac{ P(t, T)  }{P(0, T)}  \exp \left( -\int^t_0 r_s ds \right) 
  \end{eqnarray}

$\square$

(4) My answer

- Apply It$\hat{o}$'s formula according to the instructions of the question. When applying It$\hat{o}$'s formula, let the expectation value $\Psi(t)$.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  d \Psi(t) &=& d \left( E^{\mathbb{P}} \left[ \frac{ d \tilde{ \mathbb{P} } }{d \mathbb{P} } \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right]  \right) \\
  &=& d \left(  \frac{ P(t, T)  }{P(0, T)}  \exp \left( -\int^t_0 r_s ds \right)  \right) \\
  &=& \frac{ 1 }{P(0, T)}  d \left( P(t, T)  \exp \left( -\int^t_0 r_s ds \right)  \right) \\
  &=& \frac{ 1 }{P(0, T)} \left(  - \sigma (T-t) \exp \left( -\int^t_0 r_s ds \right)  \ P(t, T)  dW_t \right) \\
  &=& - \sigma (T-t)  \left(  \frac{ P(t, T)  }{P(0, T)}  \exp \left( -\int^t_0 r_s ds \right)  \right)  dW_t \\
  &=& - \sigma (T-t) \Psi(t) dW_t 
  \end{eqnarray}

$\square$

(5) My answer

- Solve the S.D.E of (4) that is $d \Psi(t)  = - \sigma (T-t) \Psi(t) dW_t $ using It$\hat{o}$'s formula. Let $f(t, \Psi)=log \Psi$. 
  \begin{eqnarray}
  d \log \Psi(t) &=& 0 \ dt + \frac{1}{ \Psi(t) } d \Psi(t) + \frac{1}{2} \left( -  \frac{1}{ \Psi(t)^2 } \right) d[ \Psi(t) ] \\
  &=& \frac{1}{ \Psi(t) } \left( - \sigma (T-t) \Psi(t) dW_t \right)  -  \frac{1}{2}  \frac{1}{ \Psi(t)^2 } \sigma^2 (T-t)^2 \Psi(t)^2 dt \\
  &=&  -  \frac{1}{2}  \sigma^2 (T-t)^2 dt - \sigma (T-t)  dW_t 
  \end{eqnarray}
- Let $\psi_t = \sigma (T-t) $.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  d \log \Psi(t) &=&-  \frac{1}{2}  \sigma^2 (T-t)^2 dt - \sigma (T-t)  dW_t \\
  &=& -  \frac{1}{2} \psi_t^2 dt -\psi_tdW_t \\
  \int^t_0 d \log \Psi(s) &=&  -  \frac{1}{2} \int^t_0 \psi_s^2 ds - \int^t_0 \psi_s dW_s \\
  \Psi(t) &=& \Psi(0) \exp \left(  -  \frac{1}{2} \int^t_0 \psi_s^2 ds - \int^t_0 \psi_s dW_s \right)
  \end{eqnarray}
- Here, one computes $\Psi(0)$.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  \Psi(t) &=&  \frac{ P(t, T)  }{P(0, T)}  \exp \left( -\int^t_0 r_s ds \right) \\
  \Psi(0) &=&  \frac{ P(0, T)  }{P(0, T)}  \exp \left( -\int^0_0 r_s ds \right) \\
  &=& 1 \  \exp ( 0) \\
  &=& 1
  \end{eqnarray}
- Substitute the above result into the $\Psi(t) $.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  \Psi(t) &=& \Psi(0) \exp \left(  -  \frac{1}{2} \int^t_0 \psi_s^2 ds - \int^t_0 \psi_s dW_s \right) \\
  &=& \exp \left(  -  \frac{1}{2} \int^t_0 \psi_s^2 ds - \int^t_0 \psi_s dW_s \right)
  \end{eqnarray}
- Therefore, one computes $\tilde{ \mathbb{P} }/ \mathbb{P}$ the according to the instructions of the question.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  \frac{\tilde{ \mathbb{P} }}{ \mathbb{P} }&=& \frac{1}{P(0, T)} \exp \left( -  \int^T_0 r_s ds  \right) \\
  &=&  E^{\mathbb{P}} \left[ \frac{1}{P(0, T)} \exp \left( -  \int^T_0 r_s ds  \right) \middle| \mathcal{F}_T \right] \\
  &=& E^{\mathbb{P}} \left[ \frac{P(T, T)}{P(0, T)} \exp \left( -  \int^T_0 r_s ds  \right) \middle| \mathcal{F}_T \right] \\
  &=& E^{\mathbb{P}} \left[ \frac{ d \tilde{ \mathbb{P} } }{d \mathbb{P} } \middle| \mathcal{F}_T \right] \\
  &=& \Psi(T) \\
  &=& \exp \left(  -  \frac{1}{2} \int^T_0 \psi_s^2 ds - \int^T_0 \psi_s dW_s \right)
  \end{eqnarray}

$\square$

(6) My answer

- One reaches the following equation by Girsanov-Maruyama Theorem.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  \tilde{ W_t } &=& W_t + \int^t_0 \psi_s ds \\
  d\tilde{ W_t } &=& dW_t + \psi_t dt \\
  dW_t &=& d\tilde{ W_t } -  \psi_t dt
  \end{eqnarray}
- Recall the definition of $dr_t=\theta dt+ \sigma dW_t$ at in Exercise 4.1. Moreover, substitute the above result into the $dr_t$.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  dr_t&=&\theta dt+ \sigma dW_t \\
  &=&\theta dt+ \sigma (d\tilde{ W_t } -  \psi_t dt) \\
  &=& ( \theta - \sigma \psi_t  ) dt + \sigma d\tilde{ W_t } \\
  &=& \left(  \theta - \sigma \ \sigma (T-t) \right) dt + \sigma d\tilde{ W_t } \\
  &=& \left(  \theta - \sigma^2 (T-t) \right) dt + \sigma d\tilde{ W_t } 
  \end{eqnarray}

$\square$

### (7) My answer (under consultation)

- One shows the equation. 
  \begin{eqnarray}
  && E^{\mathbb{P}} \left[ \exp \left(- \int^T_t r_s ds \right) \cdot ( P(T,S) - K )^+  \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right]  \nonumber \\
  && \quad = E^{\tilde{\mathbb{P}}} \left[ \frac{P(t, T)}{P(t, T)} \exp \left( -\int^T_t r_s ds \right) \cdot ( P(T,S) - K )^+  \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right]  \\
  && \quad = P(t, T) E^{\tilde{\mathbb{P}}} \left[ \frac{1}{P(T, T)} \cdot ( P(T,S) - K )^+  \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right]  \\
  && \quad = P(t, T) E^{\tilde{\mathbb{P}}} \left[ ( P(T,S) - K )^+  \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right]  
  \end{eqnarray}
- Here, one computes $P(T,S)$. Recall (1). 
  \begin{eqnarray}
  P(t, T) &=&\exp \left( - ( r_0 + \theta t+ \sigma W_t ) (T-t) - \frac{1}{2} \theta (T-t)^2  + \frac{ \sigma^2}{6}  (T-t)^3  \right) \\
  P(T, S) &=&\exp \left( - ( r_0 + \theta T+ \sigma W_T) (S-T) \right) \nonumber \\
  && \qquad \cdot \exp \left( - \frac{1}{2} \theta (S-T)^2  + \frac{ \sigma^2}{6}  (S-T)^3  \right) \\
  &=&\exp \left( - ( r_0 + \theta T+ \sigma W_T) (S-T) \right) \nonumber \\
  && \qquad \cdot \exp \left( - \frac{1}{2} \theta (S-T)^2  + \frac{ \sigma^2}{6}  (S-T)^3  \right)
  \end{eqnarray}
- Here, recall the following equation by Girsanov-Maruyama Theorem.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  dW_t &=& d\tilde{ W_t } -  \psi_t dt \\
  \int^T_0 dW_t &=& \int^T_0 d\tilde{ W_t } -  \int^T_0 \sigma (T-t) dt \\
  W_T &=& \tilde{ W_T } - \sigma \left[ Tt - \frac{1}{2} t^2 \right]^T_0 \\
  &=& \tilde{ W_T } - \sigma \left( T^2 - \frac{1}{2} T^2 \right) \\
  &=& \tilde{ W_T } - \sigma  \frac{1}{2} T^2 
  \end{eqnarray}
- Substitute the above result into the $P(T, S) $.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  P(T, S) &=&\exp \left( - ( r_0 + \theta T+ \sigma W_T ) (S-T) \right) \nonumber \\
  && \qquad \cdot \exp \left( - \frac{1}{2} \theta (S-T)^2  + \frac{ \sigma^2}{6}  (S-T)^3  \right) \\
  &=&\exp \left( - \left(  r_0 + \theta T+ \sigma \left( \tilde{ W_T } - \sigma  \frac{1}{2} T^2  \right) \right) (S-T) \right) \nonumber \\
  && \qquad \cdot \exp \left( - \frac{1}{2} \theta (S-T)^2  + \frac{ \sigma^2}{6}  (S-T)^3  \right) 
  \end{eqnarray}
- Here, one computes the exponent part. Let the exponent part $\mathscr{P}(t, W)$.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  && \mathscr{P}(t, W) \nonumber \\
  && \quad = - \left(  r_0 + \theta T+ \sigma \left( \tilde{ W_T } - \sigma  \frac{1}{2} T^2  \right) \right) (S-T)  \nonumber \\
  && \qquad     - \frac{1}{2} \theta (S-T)^2  + \frac{ \sigma^2}{6}  (S-T)^3 \\
  && \quad = -r_0 (S-T)  - \theta T(S-T) -  \sigma  \tilde{ W_T }  (S-T)  \nonumber \\
  && \qquad   + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 T^2 (S-T) - \frac{1}{2} \theta (S-T)^2  + \frac{ \sigma^2}{6}  (S-T)^3 \\
  && \quad = -r_0 (S-T)   - \theta (S-T) \left( T+ \frac{S-T}{2} \right)  + \frac{ \sigma^2}{6}  (S-T)^3  \nonumber \\
  && \qquad   + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 T^2 (S-T)  -  \sigma  \tilde{ W_T }  (S-T) \\
  && \quad = -r_0 (S-T)   - \theta (S-T) \left( T+ \frac{S-T}{2} \right)  + \frac{ \sigma^2}{6}  (S-T)^3  \nonumber \\
  && \qquad  + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 T^2 (S-T) -  \sigma  \tilde{ W_t }  (S-T)  -  \sigma  \tilde{ W_T }  (S-T) +  \sigma  \tilde{ W_t }  (S-T) \\
  && \quad = -r_0 (S-T)   - \frac{1}{2} \theta (S-T) (S+T) + \frac{ \sigma^2}{6}  (S-T)^3 \nonumber \\
  && \qquad    - \sigma \left( - \sigma \frac{1}{2}T^2   +   \tilde{ W_t } \right) (S-T)   -  \sigma \left( \tilde{ W_T }  -   \tilde{ W_t } \right) (S-T) \\
  && \quad = -r_0 (S-T)   - \frac{1}{2} \theta (S^2-T^2)  + \frac{ \sigma^2}{6}  (S-T)^3 \nonumber \\
  && \qquad     - \sigma \left( - \frac{1}{2 }\sigma T^2   +   W_t + \frac{1}{2}\sigma t^2   \right) (S-T) \nonumber \\
  &&  \qquad   -  \sigma \left(  W_T + \frac{1}{2 } \sigma T^2   -   W_t - \frac{1}{2}\sigma t^2  \right) (S-T) 
  \end{eqnarray}
- Here, one computes the last 2 terms with letting those $\mathscr{Q}(t, W)$.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  \mathscr{Q}(t, W) &=&   - \sigma \left( - \frac{1}{2}\sigma T^2   +   W_t + \frac{1}{2 }\sigma t^2   \right) (S-T) \nonumber \\
  &&  \qquad  -  \sigma \left(  W_T + \frac{1}{2}\sigma T^2   -   W_t - \frac{1}{2 }\sigma t^2  \right) (S-T) \\
  %&=&    - \sigma \left( - \frac{1}{2 }\sigma T^2    + \frac{1}{2 }\sigma t^2  +   W_t \right) (S-T) \nonumber \\
  %&&  \qquad  -  \sigma \left(  (W_T -   W_t)  + \frac{1}{2 }\sigma(T-t)^2   +\frac{1}{2 }\sigma2Tt  \right) (S-T) \\
  &=&    - \sigma \left( - \frac{1}{2 }\sigma T^2   + \frac{1}{2 }\sigma t^2 +   W_t   \right) (S-T) \nonumber \\
  &&  \qquad  -  \sigma \left(  (W_T -   W_t)  + \frac{1}{2 }\sigma(T-t)^2   + \sigma Tt  \right) (S-T) \\
  &=&   - \sigma \left( - \frac{1}{2 }\sigma T^2   + \frac{1}{2 }\sigma t^2 + \sigma Tt  +   W_t   \right) (S-T) \nonumber \\
  &&  \qquad  -  \sigma \left(  (W_T -   W_t)  + \frac{1}{2 }\sigma(T-t)^2   \right) (S-T) \\
  &=&   \sigma \left( \frac{1}{2 }\sigma T^2   - \frac{1}{2 }\sigma t^2 - \sigma Tt  -  W_t   \right) (S-T) \nonumber \\
  &&  \qquad  -  \sigma \left(  (W_T -   W_t)  + \frac{1}{2 }\sigma(T-t)^2   \right) (S-T)
  \end{eqnarray}
- Substitute the above result into the $\mathscr{P}(t, W)$.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  \mathscr{P}(t, W) &=& -r_0 (S-T)   - \frac{1}{2} \theta (S^2-T^2)  + \frac{ \sigma^2}{6}  (S-T)^3 \nonumber \\
  && \qquad     - \sigma \left( - \frac{1}{2 }\sigma T^2   +   W_t + \frac{1}{2}\sigma t^2   \right) (S-T) \nonumber \\
  &&  \qquad   -  \sigma \left(  W_T + \frac{1}{2 } \sigma T^2   -   W_t - \frac{1}{2}\sigma t^2  \right) (S-T) \\
  &=& -r_0 (S-T)   - \frac{1}{2} \theta (S^2-T^2)  + \frac{ \sigma^2}{6}  (S-T)^3 \nonumber \\
  && \qquad +\sigma \left( \frac{1}{2 }\sigma T^2   + \frac{1}{2 }\sigma t^2 - \sigma Tt  -  W_t   \right) (S-T) \nonumber \\
  &&  \qquad  -  \sigma \left(  (W_T -   W_t)  + \frac{1}{2 }\sigma(T-t)^2   \right) (S-T) \\
  &=& m +X
  \end{eqnarray}
- Here, let $m$ and $X$ as below, respectively. 
  \begin{eqnarray}
  m&=& -r_0 (S-T)   - \frac{1}{2} \theta (S^2-T^2)  + \frac{ \sigma^2}{6}  (S-T)^3 \nonumber \\
  && \qquad +\sigma \left( \frac{1}{2 }\sigma T^2   + \frac{1}{2 }\sigma t^2 - \sigma Tt  -  W_t   \right) (S-T)  \\
  X&=&  -  \sigma \left(  (W_T -   W_t)  + \frac{1}{2 }\sigma(T-t)^2   \right) (S-T)
  \end{eqnarray}
- Therefore, $v^2$ is computed as below.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  && E^{ \{ \mathbb{P},  X \}} \left[ X \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right] \nonumber \\
  && \qquad =  E^{ \{ \mathbb{P},  X\}} \left[  -  \sigma \left(  (W_T -   W_t)  + \frac{1}{2 }\sigma(T-t)^2   \right) (S-T)\middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right] \\
  && \qquad =  -  \frac{1}{2 }\sigma^2 (T-t)^2    (S-T) \\
  && \qquad = \frac{1}{2 }\sigma^2 (T-t)^2   (T-S)  \\
  && E^{ \{ \mathbb{P},  X \}} \left[ X^2 \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right] \nonumber \\
  && \qquad =   E^{ \{ \mathbb{P},  X\}} \left[ \left( -  \sigma \left(  (W_T -   W_t)  + \frac{1}{2 }\sigma(T-t)^2   \right) (S-T) \right)^2 \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right] \\
  && \qquad =   E^{ \{ \mathbb{P},  X\}} \left[ \left(  \sigma \left(  (W_T -   W_t)  + \frac{1}{2 }\sigma(T-t)^2   \right) (T-S) \right)^2 \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right] \\
  && \qquad = E^{ \{ \mathbb{P},  X\}} \left[ \sigma^2 (W_T -   W_t) ^2 (T-S)^2   \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right] \nonumber \\
  && \qquad \qquad + E^{ \{ \mathbb{P},  X\}} \left[ \sigma^2 (W_T -   W_t) \frac{1}{2 } \ 2 \ \sigma(T-t)^2 (T-S)  \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right] \nonumber \\
  && \qquad \qquad +  E^{ \{ \mathbb{P},  X\}} \left[ \sigma^2 \frac{1}{4 }\sigma^2 (T-t)^4  (T-S) ^2   \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right] \\
  && \qquad = \sigma^2 (T -   t) (T-S)^2  + \frac{1}{4 }\sigma^4 (T-t)^4  (T-S) ^2   \\
  && Var^{ \{ \mathbb{P},  X \}}  \left( X \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right) \nonumber \\
  && \qquad \equiv  E^{ \{ \mathbb{P},  X \}} \left[ X^2 \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right] -\left( E^{ \{ \mathbb{P},  X \}} \left[ X \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right] \right)^2 \\
  && \qquad =  \sigma^2 (T -   t)  (T-S)^2  + \frac{1}{4 }\sigma^4 (T-t)^4  (T-S) ^2  \nonumber \\
  && \qquad \qquad -  \left( -  \frac{1}{2 }\sigma^2 (T-t)^2    (T-S) \right)^2 \\
  && \qquad =  \sigma^2 (T -   t)  (T-S)^2  = v^2
  \end{eqnarray}
- Hence, one reaches below equations.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  && E^{\mathbb{P}} \left[ \exp \left(- \int^T_t r_s ds \right) \cdot ( P(T,S) - K )^+  \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right]  \nonumber \\
  && \quad = P(t, T) E^{\tilde{\mathbb{P}}} \left[ ( P(T,S) - K )^+  \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right]  \\
  && \quad = P(t, T) E^{ \{ \mathbb{P}, X \} } \left[ (e^{m+X} - K )^+  \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right]  \\
  && \quad = P(t, T) e^{m+ v^2/2} N\left(  v + \frac{m - \log K}{v} \right) -P(t, T)  K N\left( \frac{m - \log K}{v} \right) 
  \end{eqnarray}
- where
  \begin{eqnarray}
  \phi(y) &=& \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-y^2/2} \\
  N(z)&=& \int^z_{ - \infty}  \phi(y) dy
  \end{eqnarray}
- Next, one computes $E^{ \{ \mathbb{P}, X \} } \left[ e^{m+X} \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right] $.
  \begin{eqnarray} 
  E^{ \{ \mathbb{P}, X \} } \left[ e^{m+X} \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right] &=& e^m E^{ \{ \mathbb{P}, X \} } \left[ e^X \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right] \\
  &=& e^m \int^{}_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{1}{ \sqrt{2 \pi v^2} } e^x \ e^{-x^2/(2v^2)} dx \\
  &=& e^m \int^{}_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{1}{ \sqrt{2 \pi v^2} } e^{ -(x^2-2v^2x)/(2v^2)} dx\\
  &=& e^{m+v^2/2}  \int^{}_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{1}{ \sqrt{2 \pi v^2} } e^{ -(x^2 - v^2)/(2v^2)} dx \\
  &=& e^{m+v^2/2}  
  \end{eqnarray}
- Therefore, one reaches the following equations.
  \begin{eqnarray} 
  E^{\tilde{\mathbb{P}}} \left[  P(T,S)   \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right]  &=&  E^{\tilde{\mathbb{P}}} \left[  \frac{P(T,S)}{1}   \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right] \\
  &=& E^{\tilde{\mathbb{P}}} \left[  \frac{P(T,S)}{P(T,T)}   \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right] \\
  &=& E^{\mathbb{P}} \left[  \frac{\exp \left( -\int^T_0 r_s ds \right)}{P(0,T)} P(T,S)  \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right] \\
  &=& \frac{\exp \left( -\int^t_0 r_s ds \right)}{P(0,T)} E^{\mathbb{P}} \left[ \exp \left( -\int^T_t r_s ds \right) P(T,S)  \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right] \\
  &=& \frac{1}{P(t,T)} E^{\mathbb{P}} \left[  P(t,S)  \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right] \\
  &=& \frac{P(t,S) }{P(t,T)} E^{\mathbb{P}} \left[  \ 1 \ \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right] \\
  &=& \frac{P(t,S) }{P(t,T)} \\
  E^{\tilde{\mathbb{P}}} \left[  P(T,S)   \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right]  &=& E^{ \{ \mathbb{P}, X \} } \left[ e^{m+X} \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right] \\
  &=& e^{m+v^2/2}  
  \end{eqnarray}
- Then, one reaches the following equations.
  \begin{eqnarray} 
  e^{m+v^2/2}   &=&  \frac{P(t,S) }{P(t,T)} \\
  m+ \frac{v^2}{2} &=&  \log \frac{P(t,S) }{P(t,T)} \\
  \end{eqnarray} 
  \item Moreover, one reaches the following equations.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  \frac{m}{v} + \frac{v}{2} &=&  \frac{1}{v} \log \frac{P(t,S) }{P(t,T)} \\
  \frac{m}{v} &=& - \frac{v}{2}  +  \frac{1}{v} \log \frac{P(t,S) }{P(t,T)} \\
  \frac{m}{v} -\frac{\log K}{v} &=& - \frac{v}{2}  +  \frac{1}{v} \log \frac{P(t,S) }{P(t,T)} -\frac{\log K}{v}\\
  \frac{m - \log K}{v} &=& - \frac{v}{2}  +  \frac{1}{v} \log \frac{P(t,S) }{K \ P(t,T)}
  \end{eqnarray}
- Hence, substitute the above result into the expectation value. One reaches this answer.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  && E^{\mathbb{P}} \left[ \exp \left(- \int^T_t r_s ds \right) \cdot ( P(T,S) - K )^+  \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right]  \nonumber \\
  && \quad = P(t, T) e^{m+ v^2/2} N\left(  v + \frac{m - \log K}{v} \right) -P(t, T)  K N\left( \frac{m - \log K}{v} \right)  \\
  && \quad = P(t, T) \frac{P(t,S) }{P(t,T)}  N\left(  v  - \frac{v}{2}  +  \frac{1}{v} \log \frac{P(t,S) }{K \ P(t,T)} \right)  \nonumber \\
  && \qquad -P(t, T)  K N\left( - \frac{v}{2}  +  \frac{1}{v} \log \frac{P(t,S) }{K \ P(t,T)}\right)  \\
  && \quad = P(t,S)   N\left(   \frac{v}{2}  +  \frac{1}{v} \log \frac{P(t,S) }{K \ P(t,T)} \right)  \nonumber \\
  && \qquad -P(t, T)  K N\left( - \frac{v}{2}  +  \frac{1}{v} \log \frac{P(t,S) }{K \ P(t,T)}\right)  
  \end{eqnarray}
- where $ v = \sigma (T -   S) \sqrt{T-t} $.

$\square$

### Thank you.